# Swift nil is not the same as Objective-C nil

Tags: objective-c, swift

Apple documentation mentions that:

> Swift’s nil is not the same as nil in Objective-C. In Objective-C, nil
>   is a pointer to a non-existent object. In Swift, nil is not a
>   pointer—it is the absence of a value of a certain type. Optionals of
>   any type can be set to nil, not just object types

When is the above knowledge useful?
Will compiler convert Swift nil to Objective-C nil and vice versa automatically where applicable?

Comment: The above knowledge is always useful.

Comment: @matt, I am not saying it's not useful - I am asking when we should be mindful of this knowledge or when it will be useful to keep in mind when coding.

Comment: Okay, then: It will be useful every time you use the word "nil" in Swift, every time you test for nil, and every time you send or receive a value between Swift and Objective-C.

Comment: @Matt Useful in what way? Even without knowing it, nothing harm will come of it in the use cases you mentioned, right?

Comment: Useful because understanding what you are doing is better than not understanding it. I have written at this point thousands of lines of Swift code, and knowing what "nil" means was useful all the time — just as knowing function syntax was useful all the time.

Comment: I understand and agree with you on your philosophy.  For this particular post, I am looking for specific reasons.

Comment: I have scored the highest downvotes on a question that didn't get closed.  There should be a badge for this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, the compiler will convert Objective-C nils to Swift nils. That is why when translating from Objective-C all pointers must become optionals in Swift.

The usefulness of this knowledge is right in the description you gave:

> Optionals of any type can be set to nil, not just object types

In Swift all types can be made optional and therefore `nil`. For example, in Objective-C you cannot make an NSInteger nil.

Technically `nil` is just a case in the Optional enum:

```
enum Optional<T> {
    case None
    case Some(T)
}
```

`nil` is just shorthand for the `None` case

Comment: I like the last note that nil is just a shorthand for None. Is there a way to prove this via code?

Comment: It's in the header, as he just showed you. What more do you want? Every Optional is actually an enum consisting of either None (nil) or a value (Some "wrapping" the real value). That is what nil is in Swift.

Comment: I was looking for something like this: Optional.None === nil.  I verified and it's indeed the case.  Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

First, that means that only optionals can have a nil value, e.g.:

```
// Objc:
Object *foo = nil;
foo = [Object new];
foo = nil;

// Swift
var foo: Object = nil // not allowed
var bar: Object = Object()
bar = nil // not allowed

var foo: Object? = nil // fine
foo = Object()
foo = nil
```

But the more important application is in primitive types. If you have an int in objc, and it might have an invalid value, you need to decide on that invalid value and make sure both caller and callee know it.

```
// Objc
int i = 0; // Is this valid? 
i = -1 // What about this?

// Swift
var bar: int? = nil // Invalid.
bar = 0  // valid.
bar = -1 // valid.
```