# how can I reload a View iOS swift, MFMailComposeViewController

Tags: ios, email, swift, reload

I'm trying to implement a Email functionality inside my app, I wrote this class following a tutorial:

```
import UIKit
import MessageUI

class EmailController: UIViewController, MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var subject: UITextField?
@IBOutlet weak var body: UITextView?
var alert: UIAlertView = UIAlertView()
var subjectText:String?
var bodyText:String?
var toSomeone:AnyObject!
var mailController:MFMailComposeViewController = MFMailComposeViewController()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    //AlertView
    alert.title = "Error"
    alert.message = "Faltan datos"
    alert.addButtonWithTitle("Ok")
    //Recipients
    toSomeone = "xxxxxx@gmail.com"
    //asignar delegado al controlador de email
    mailController.mailComposeDelegate = self


}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
}



@IBAction func sendEmail(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {

    //bool var becouse optionals can't be used like bools
    var condicion1:Bool? = subject?.text.isEmpty
    var condicion2:Bool? = body?.text.isEmpty

    //unwraped the variables
    if (!condicion1! && !condicion2!) {

        subjectText = self.subject!.text
        bodyText = self.body!.text

        //Completar objeto mailController

        mailController.setSubject(subjectText)
        mailController.setMessageBody(bodyText, isHTML: false)

        var recipients = [toSomeone]

        mailController.setToRecipients(recipients)

        self.presentViewController(mailController, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }else {

        self.alert.show()

    }




}


func  mailComposeController(controller: MFMailComposeViewController!, didFinishWithResult result: MFMailComposeResult, error: NSError!) {


    switch result.value {

    case MFMailComposeResultCancelled.value:
        //se cancelo envio
        alert.title = "Envio cancelado"
        alert.message = "Se cancelo el envio"
        alert.addButtonWithTitle("Ok")
        alert.show()

    case MFMailComposeResultSaved.value:
        //se guardo draft
        alert.title = "Correo guardado"
        alert.message = "Se guardo el correo en la app de Mail"
        alert.addButtonWithTitle("Ok")
        alert.show()

    case MFMailComposeResultFailed.value:
        //fallo el envio
        alert.title = "Error"
        alert.message = "El correo no pudo ser enviado"
        alert.addButtonWithTitle("Ok")
        alert.show()

    case MFMailComposeResultSent.value:
        //el mail se pudo enviar y esta en la pila de envio
        alert.title = "Correo enviado"
        alert.message = "El correo se envio exitosamente"
        alert.addButtonWithTitle("Ok")
        alert.show()

    default:
        break


    }

                                                    //bloque de codigo a ejecutar al finalizar de mostrar la vista
    mailController.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, nil)



     }

   }
```

I can send the email just fine but when I dismiss the mail view I see my initial view (thats ok) the problem is that if I try to invoke the email view again(I mean try to send another email) the program don't respond and I can't dismiss it anymore, I think that I need to reload the initial view???

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can present a new `MFMailComposeViewController` each time you send an email, like this

```
mailController = MFMailComposeViewController()
```

Declare it like this.

```
var mailController:MFMailComposeViewController?
```

Comment: Cool! your solution works! : D I just have one more question, How de-alocate my objects? if I am not wrong I can execute code after my mail view get dismiss with this method:   mailController?.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, nil), but I don't know how to put a block of code inside that method and I don't know how to set the memory free for my objects, I think it's something like this maybe? : object1 = nil  . Thanks for your help!

Comment: If you declare `var mailController:MFMailComposeViewController?`, you can use `mailController = .None` or `mailController = nil` to set it to nil. More from [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24372352/4016786)

Comment: ok :), but do you know how to put a block of code here (in the completion parameter)? self.presentViewController(mailController, animated: true, completion: nil) I tried with a clousure but I think I put it in the wrong way

Comment: Please try this:`self.presentViewController(mailController!, animated: true, completion: { () -> Void in
                println(self.presentedViewController)
            })
`